# Reading objects from text file

Tags: java, android

I have a text file with serialized objects written it. The file contains data like this -

```
line[com.high.3449%]
line[com.high.58850?]
line[com.high.47646%]
```

I want to read this and store 1 by 1 in an arraylist. But when I read it I am just able to read the first line which is `line[com.high.3449%]` but not everything. I am using below logic to read -

```
List<MyData> myobjects1 = new ArrayList<MyData>();
List<MyData> myobjects2 = new ArrayList<MyData>(); 
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/storage/200B-431F/Documents/MyData.txt");
ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
try {
    myobjects1 = (List<MyData>) ois.readObject();
    while (myobjects1 != null) {
        myobjects2.addAll(myobjects1);
        Log.d("hi", "second arraylist " + myobjects2);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

try {
    ois.close();
    server.sendData(myobjects2);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

Can someone help me how to read all the data and store in the arraylist `myobjects2`?

Comment: Sorry, but I dont think you will be able to get the deserialized data from the text file. 'line[com.high.3449%]' this is nothing but just a simple text now.

Comment: This is what i need. I am just getting the first line but not the rest.  I want to iterate over my file and get all the data

Comment: you mean you want to have list something like this? :line[com.high.3449%]
line[com.high.58850?]
line[com.high.47646%]

Comment: Yeah and store it in the arraylist myobjects2

Comment: Can you attach the MyData class please.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to your loop when you read back the data.  There is no need to loop (it will loop forever)

Instead of

```
myobjects1 = (List<MyData>) ois.readObject();
while (myobjects1 != null) {
   myobjects2.addAll(myobjects1);
   ...
```

You should use

```
myobjects1 = (List<MyData>) ois.readObject();
if (myobjects1 != null) {
   myobjects2.addAll(myobjects1);
}
```

If you want to loop through the myobjects you need to use something like

```
for (MyData myData : myobjects1) {
   myobjects2.add(myData);
}
```

Am adding the code I used to test the answer.

```
package test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class LoadFileObject {

    public static class MyData implements Serializable {
        private String line, content;

        public MyData(String line, String content) {
            setLine(line);
            setContent(content);
        }
        public String getLine() {
            return line;
        }
        public void setLine(String line) {
            this.line = line;
        }
        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content= content;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return (line+content);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void doWork() throws Exception {
        List<MyData> myobjects1 = new ArrayList<MyData>();
        myobjects1.add(new MyData("l1", "content1"));
        myobjects1.add(new MyData("l2", "content2"));

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("mydata.txt"));
        oos.writeObject(myobjects1);
        oos.close();

        List<MyData> myobjects2 = new ArrayList<MyData>(); 
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("mydata.txt"));
        myobjects2 = (List<MyData>) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("read:" + myobjects2.size());
        for (MyData myData : myobjects2) {
            System.out.println("myData line:" + myData.getLine() + " content:" + myData.getContent());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It is the same problem. It is just reading the first line of the file

Comment: There may be some issue with how you have written the data or with your MyData object. I'm going to attach my test case which shows that the code works.

Comment: I am able to see the logs while being written and it is the log which i pasted above

Comment: Did you see the System.out.println("myData line:" + myData.getLine() + " content:" + myData.getContent()); that shows the data has been read back into the MyData object?

Comment: Yes i checked it in my code, same problem. I think readObject() is not iterating and is reading the first object only not the rest

Comment: Not quite, the readObject is reading back a list of the objects that were serialized into the file. As it's a list you need to check the size() method to see how many objects were read as I've shown in the test code.  You also need to iterate over the list which I've also demonstrated.

Comment: @FAZ Please double check that the file indeed contains several lines, and that you didn't, for example, overwrite it with something like `echo foo > MyData.txt`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
       FileInputStream fis = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream("/storage/200B-431F/Documents/MyData.txt/CPU.txt");
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                    System.out.println("Reading File line by line using BufferedReader");

                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    while(line != null){
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = reader.readLine();
                        // here line variable will hold the data for each line of your text file
                        // i.e you can add the string to the arrayList here
                          myObjects2.add(line);
                    }           

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                            } 
                 catch (IOException ex) {

                 }
```

Comment: Line is string and how can i add string to arraylist which is not string arraylist

Comment: oh ok, then thats what i said, that the line read from text file will be of string type and not MyData type object.

Comment: You can make InputStream from that string, and create ObjectInputStream from it `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes()));`